# Can a Samsung Gear s3 Tizen web app push data to a remote SQL database?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I know this is possible on Tizen mobile web apps using the Web SQL database API, but can it also be done from a wearable? I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Web SQL is supported in mobile applications only till now. You can find Web SQL related document from [here](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/web-application/w3chtml5supplementary-features/storage/web-sql-database).

For wearables (Gear), you can use [Localstorage](http://denvycom.com/blog/how-to-store-data-in-your-gear-2-apps/) to store data.

Comment: Why is this? Is it because PHP is not supported? Could the data in Localstorage be redirected to a web app and then pushed to a SQL db?

Comment: No may be..because mobile app is supported it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of incongruity between the subject of your post and what you are asking in it. In the subject you are asking about saving data to a remote (external) source but in the body you are asking about the availability of Web SQL on the watch.

To address the question in your subject line, if you want to save data to an external source that source is going to need to expose a web service of some type or another. This also means that the web service will need to be exposed to the internet; it will need to run on a machine that allows incoming traffic from the Internet *unless* you only intend for this database to be accessible to others that are on the same network.

Without knowing exactly what you are doing it is difficult to give you advice on what direction to go in. There's a number of potential solutions from deploying a MySQL database with the REST plugin to making use of AWS or Azure. There are also security considerations. If you can give more detail about your intended outcome then more direction can be shared.